# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177) Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: laravel, flutter, laravel-api

I am trying to build an application with flutter and laravel api. it was going good till i started implementing the `login` functionality. I am getting this error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.`
Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?
In case I made a silly mistake, please don't be mad I am just getting started with programming.
Thanks a lot!
Login function code

````
    var _userService = UserService();
    var registeredUser = await _userService.login(user);
    var result = json.decode(registeredUser.body);
    print(result);
    if(result['success']['result']== true){
      SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _prefs.setInt('userId', result['success']['user']['id']);
      _prefs.setString('userName', result['success']['user']['name']);
      _prefs.setString('userPhone', result['success']['user']['phone']);
      _prefs.setString('userEmail', result['success']['user']['email']);
      _prefs.setString('token', result['success']['token']);
      // Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      //   Navigator.pop(context);
      //   Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, DashboardScreen.id);
      // });
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
    }  else {
      displayToastMessage('Failed to login!', context);
    }
  }```

When I press `Login button` this is how I call the `login` function.
```onPressed: () {
          if(!emailTextEditingController.text
              .contains("@")) {
            displayToastMessage(
                "Not a valid email address", context);
          }
          else if(passwordTextEditingController.text.length < 6) {
            displayToastMessage(
                "Password must be at least 6 characters", context);
          }  else {
            var user = User();
            // user.name = nameTextEditingController.text;
            user.email = emailTextEditingController.text;
            // user.phone = phoneTextEditingController.text;
            user.password = passwordTextEditingController.text;
            _login(context, user);
          }
        },```

This is the UsersService Code for login
`login(User user) async {
    return await _repository.httpPost('login', user.toJson());
  }`

and `_repositpry` is the one sending request to the `api`
here is how it is implemented 
`  String _baseUrl = 'https://api.adikatour.com/api';
   httpPost(String api, data) async {
    return await http.post(_baseUrl + "/" + api, body: data);
  }`

and here is the api code for login
` public function login(){ 
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
            $success['name'] =  $user->name;
            $success['user'] =  $user;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus); 
        } 
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }`

can you please tell me why I am getting this error? thanks again!
````

Comment: If you can't be sure that a String is not null, always check it for null before getting its length. In your case, it would be: `passwordTextEditingController?.text != null && passwordTextEditingController.text.length < 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem.
This is how I structured my used model.

```
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String password;

  toJson(){
    return {
      'id' : id.toString(),
      'name' : name,
      'email' : email,
      'phone' : phone,
      'password' : password,
    };
  }
}
```

But in the _login function, only email and password were set. since my server doesn't allow null values for `phone` and `name` fields, I have to convert those fields to not null. so, I converted the user model like this. then it is solved.

```
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String password;

  toJson(){
    return {
      'id' : id.toString(),
      'name' : name.toString(),
      'email' : email.toString(),
      'phone' : phone.toString(),
      'password' : password.toString(),
    };
  }
}
```

Thank you guys for helping me, I really appreciate it. Special thanks to @sajith lakmal

Answer (score 0):

Try this as on pressed: -

```
onPressed: () {
      if(!emailTextEditingController.text
          .contains("@")) {
        displayToastMessage(
            "Not a valid email address", context);
      }
      else if (passwordTextEditingController.text is String && ((passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0) < 6) {
        displayToastMessage(
            "Password must be at least 6 characters", context);
      }
     else if (!(passwordTextEditingController.text is String)){
        displayToastMessage(
            "Password must not be empty", context);
    }
     else {
        var user = User();
        // user.name = nameTextEditingController.text;
        user.email = emailTextEditingController.text;
        // user.phone = phoneTextEditingController.text;
        user.password = passwordTextEditingController.text;
        _login(context, user);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @sajith lakmal, the error is gone now, but the code is not being executed after the last `else if` statement. I tried to `print` on console but nothing is happening after that line. any suggestions, please?

Comment: I have edited the answer check try new answer. else code block was not executed because `else if` statement that check whether the password is an string stopped the flow of if statement.

Comment: Yeah, I checked with the new answer but still getting this error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 4538): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 4538): Tried calling: length`

Comment: Did you add the question mark (?) in passwordTextEditingController.text?.length

Comment: Yeah, I removed it still the same. I don't know why...sorry for the trouble bro

Comment: I have edited the answer again check that. Never mind.

Comment: There is a syntax error `The operands of the operator '&&' must be assignable to 'bool'` in this line of code `else if (passwordTextEditingController.text is String && (passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6) {
            displayToastMessage(
                "Password must be at least 6 characters", context);
          }`... it is returning an Int value

Comment: add parenthesis for (passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6, as ((passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6).

Comment: `((passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6)` edited as this, and getting this error `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'bool'` the code returns an int but `&&` operator needs bool value for comparison... how can i make `((passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6)` this code return bool?...I am really sorry bro...I know I am asking silly questions

Comment: sorry for my mistake. previous comment should be corrected as,                                            add parenthesis for (passwordTextEditingController.text?.length) ?? 0 < 6, as ((passwordTextEditingController.text?.length ?? 0 ) < 6).

Comment: Back to the former error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.`...Thank you very much, for your support...I will find other ways to implement it.

Comment: okay. check this blog to know more about the null aware operaters - https://flutterigniter.com/checking-null-aware-operators-dart/